# how can i dynamically submit form that has choice field and subschoice field dynamically populated

Tags: forms, model

i have a model that i defined choice field and subchoice field such that when a choice field is selected it will populate the subchoice fields and its related value whic

here is what i have tried but i am getting a error message

```py
class Broadband(models.Model):
    REGION_CHOICES = [
        ('North East', 'North East'),
        ('North West', 'North West'),
        ('South East', 'South East'),
        ('South South', 'South South'),
    ]

    STATE_CHOICES = {
        'North East': [
            ('Kano', 'Kano'),
            ('Jigawa', 'Jigawa'),
            ('Bauchi', 'Bauchi'),
            ('Yobe', 'Yobe'),
            ('Borno', 'Borno'),
            ('Adamawa', 'Adamawa'),
        ],
        'North West': [
            ('Kaduna', 'Kaduna'),
            ('Abuja', 'Abuja'),
            ('Katsina', 'Katsina'),
            ('Jos', 'Jos'),
        ],
        'South East': [
            ('Enugu', 'Enugu'),
            ('Imo', 'Imo'),
            ('Anambra', 'Anambra'),
            ('Abia', 'Abia'),
        ],
        'South South': [
            ('Bayelsa', 'Bayelsa'),
            ('Delta', 'Delta'),
            ('Port Harcourt', 'Port Harcourt'),
            ('Akwa', 'Akwa'),
            ('Cross River', 'Cross River'),
        ],
    }

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region = models.CharField(choices=REGION_CHOICES, max_length=100, default='North East')
    state = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    device_type = models.CharField(choices=DEVICE_CHOICES, max_length=100, default='MIFI')
    imei = models.IntegerField()
    msisdn = models.IntegerField()
    alternate_number= models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```py
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```